# What is the content in save() django

Tags: python, django, signals

I am trying to understand the [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) method as I am getting this error:

> save() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

So I renamed a field in my Model with an image field and a name field

I have a model in which you can upload an image and the filename will be the field's name:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_file = models.FileField(upload_to='renaming')
```

So when I use the save method through a signal I get this error:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Company)   
def rename (sender, instance, update_fields, **kwargs):
    new_name='abc'
    instance.image_file.name = new_name
    instance.image_file.save()
```

So I fill in `instance.image_file.save(new_name, instance, save =True)` Instead of `instance` I should fill in the conent which is the [object's containing the file's content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile)

But what is that? What is the content exaclty. `instance.save()` doesnt work either btw, it creates and infinite loop.

Comment: `image_field` is just a field on `SomeModel`, you don't save by field, you save the object. So you need `instance.save()` instead of `instance.image_field.save()`

Comment: Interestingly the link you are giving provides the answer to your question. It explains all the parameters.

Comment: Sadly, I don't understand it, hence the question

Comment: @Gocht `FileFields` can be persisted via their  [`.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) method.

Answer (score 1):

> instance.save() doesnt work either btw, it creates and infinite loop.

Which is exactly as it should be the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal is fired after the save() method has been called on an instance of your model somewhere in your code. Now within the post_save signal reciever you are calling save() one more time. The object will then be saved, and another post_save signal fired. Then you save the object again in the signal reciever and ...

If you want to change what's saved into the database, you should tap the `pre_save` signal instead. or you should override the SomeModel save method.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.debug("using custom save")
        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

use one or the other but not both.

Comment: not sure what you mean by this, but this doesn't change names of my files

Comment: I am showing you how to override the save method (or use pre_save) instead to change any of the table fields. In here you can change the file name as you see fit. Do that before you call super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pre_save signal in order to prevent the max recusion exceded exception.

```
from django.db.models import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Company)   
def rename (sender, instance, update_fields, **kwargs):
    new_name = 'abc'
    instance.image_file.name = new_name
    # instance.save()  # this line is covered by django, so drop it from here
```

Also note that **you must make a random `new_name`**, otherwise the image filename will be replaced everytime you save a new Company object

Comment: ok I obviously don't get it, if I use this with instance.save() it will create an infinite loop ?!

Comment: also if I use this, it changes the name of the file in the admin view but not in the databsse. if I click on the image with the new name it opens an empty page

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, just drop the `instance.save()` from there. I just remember if you use the pre_save signal, there's no need you manually call the save method; which means: use the pre_save signal, alter the image_file.name and that's it. Django is gonna to save it for you.

Comment: yes, but not in the database, if i click on the link with the new name it leads to an empty page?!